# Solidity: try / catch call to external non-existent address method

Tags: solidity, evm

I have two contracts: A and B.

`callFoo()` of contract B must call the method `foo()` of contract A. If method `foo()` exists on contract A, `callFoo()` must return `true`, `false` otherwise.

Here is the code:

```js
pragma solidity >=0.8.14;

contract A {
  function foo() external returns(bool) { return true; }
}

contract B {
  function callFoo(A _addr) public view returns(bool) {
    try _addr.foo() returns(bool) {
      return true;
    } catch(bytes memory err) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**The problem:** when invoking `callFoo()` with an address pointing to a non-deployed A contract, the call reverts regardless of `try / catch`. It looks like `try / catch` does not work if method from called contract does not exist. Is there a way to catch a call attempt to a non-existing method, or I'm bound to use `assembly`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when invoking callFoo() with an address pointing to a non-deployed A
> contract, the call reverts regardless of try / catch. It looks like
> try / catch does not work if method from called contract does not
> exist.

What's really happening is that you are expecting a return value, which is never returned because nothing ever gets executed since there is no code to execute. The revert takes place in `B` during the decoding step of the (missing) return values, never in `A` so the try / catch logic is useless here. It's only meant to catch reverts in calls as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/control-structures.html?highlight=try%20catch#try-catch) :

> Errors inside the expression are not caught (for example if it is a
> complex expression that also involves internal function calls), only a
> revert happening inside the external call itself.

and :

> If an error happens during the decoding of the return data inside a
> try/catch-statement, this causes an exception in the currently
> executing contract and because of that, it is not caught in the catch
> clause.

A first approach would be to check for the presence of some code in the target account :

```
function callFoo(A _addr) public view returns(bool) {

    uint256 csize;

    assembly {
        csize := extcodesize(_addr)
    }

    if (csize == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    try _addr.foo() returns(bool) {
        return true;
    } catch(bytes memory err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which solves your issue if `_addr` has no code associated to it. However, there is another case that you may or may not want to handle : if you call an existing contract, that doesn't revert but doesn't return the expected values you'll get the same behavior as before, as `B` will revert due to a decoding error.

```
contract B {
    function foo() external view {}
}
```

In that case, I guess that there are several solutions. The easiest one is to wrap your call into another call in order to catch decoding errors, but that's not very practical and comes with some gas overhead... :

```
function wrapCallFoo(A _addr) public view returns (bool) {
    try this.callFoo(_addr) returns (bool rvalue) {
        return rvalue;
    }

    catch (bytes memory err) {
        return false;
    }
}

function callFoo(A _addr) public view returns(bool) {

    uint256 csize;

    assembly {
        csize := extcodesize(_addr)
    }

    if (csize == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    try _addr.foo() returns(bool) {
        return true;
    } catch(bytes memory err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The other one would be full assembly, it's the only way if you want fine-grained control over everything (call + decoding) anyway, but you won't rely on the try / catch logic anymore. Let me know if you'd like an example.

I hope this answers your question.